# How to change Uninstaller icon in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I have a file compiled with NSIS.

Since MUI_ICON is used, after executing the installer file, the desired icon is displayed in the progress stage,

If you use MUI_UNICON, the desired icon is displayed in Add/Remove Programs.

However, an executable file and Uninstall.exe were created using the Installer, but

This Uninstall.exe shows the default icon for NSIS, not the one I intended.

Default icon: modern-uninstall-colorful.ico

How can I change this default icon at build time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MUI_UNICON` is correct and will change the uninstaller .exe icon.

If you see the wrong icon in Explorer then that is because it is caching the old icon. Rename your .exe and it should show the new icon. You can verify the icon by looking at the resources with [Resource Hacker](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/)...